# how to show media in pictureBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

I just want to get msg from (any) channel and if it have media (check by flag) show it in pictureBox.
howto show media in pictureBox from await client.DownloadFileAsync(photo, fileStream); or another functions with .Media field?

upd:
the correct question is: how to show *.jpg file from DownloadFileAsync without saving to disk and work only with memory?

Comment: What media do you expect? PBox can only show images. The question has nothing to do with the designer - please change the tag to winforms!

Comment: `DownloadFileAsync` expects a string and will store a file on disk. Instead use [downloaddata](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloaddata?view=net-8.0) to get a bytearray, which you can then convert to an image in memory and show it in the pbox..

Answer (score 1):

You can download the photo directly to a `MemoryStream`.

Remember to reset stream position to the beginning of file before using the downloaded content

```cs
    var memStream = new MemoryStream();
    await client.DownloadFileAsync(photo, memStream);
    memStream.Position = 0;
    pictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(memStream);
```

*Note: in order to use `await` in your code, you must make your method `async` (for example `async void`)*

Comment: Thanks! 
pictureBox_tgmedia.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
MessageMediaPhoto photo = m.media as MessageMediaPhoto;
var stream = new MemoryStream();
                        var type = await _client.DownloadFileAsync(photo.photo as Photo, stream);
                        pictureBox_tgmedia.BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);